# ошибка EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: node.js, fetch

Всем привет.
Node.js, node-fetch. Все работает, но иногда выдает ошибку

**FetchError: request to https://api.(тут я обрезал url) failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2a02:6b8::2:216:**

Почему? Как это вылечить?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Ошибка приходила из ipv6. В некоторых Линуксах, например в Ubuntu 22, ipv6 включено по умолчанию и у него приоритет перед ipv4.
Вылечилось отключением ipv6.

Comment: Это не решение проблемы. Вы же не отрезаете всю ногу которая начинает болеть?

Comment: @ГеннадийП первопричина проблемы лежит, скорее всего, в ошибке в настройке ipv6 у провайдера у которого я арендую vps, на котором происходит ошибка. До переезда к этому провайдеру ошибки не было. Согласитесь, мне не стоит пытаться решить проблему с настройками провайдера. :)

Comment: А почему вы думаете что это проблема с настройками у провайдера, а не с настройками вашего сервера? Вы пробовали обращаться в техподдержку вашего сервера?

Comment: @ГеннадийП потому что я ничего не настраивал в части сетевых протоколов, до момента отключения ipv6. Можно конечно предположить что ошибка в Ubuntu 22, но думаю об этом бы был шум на весь интернет и это бы быстро поправили. Поэтому остается провайдер.